# Resolve MAC address to vendor BASH

Tags: linux, bash, mac-address

As the title states, I was wondering if I could resolve a MAC address to a vendor on Linux, with BASH.

I would rather not use NMap, as I want it to be quick.

```
Example: e0:b9:e5:9e:59:00 -> Technicolor
```

Answer (score 2):

A MAC address starts with a 24-bit number, the first three octets, that uniquely identifies a vendor or manufacturer called the  OUI (Organizationally Unique Identifier).

OUI's are assigned by the IEEE and you can check and download the public registry here in a number of formats: https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries

From there it is a simple exercise of extracting the OUI from the MAC address and looking up the resulting OUI in that registry....